# how to implement color search with sphinx?

Tags: search, colors, search-engine, sphinx

searching a photo by dominant colors using mysql is quite simple. assuming that the r,g,b values of the most dominant colors of the photo is already stored in the database, this could be achieved for example by something like:

```
SELECT * FROM colors
WHERE    ABS(dominant_r - :r) < :threshold
AND      ABS(dominant_g - :g) < :threshold
AND      ABS(dominant_b - :b) < :threshold
```

i wonder, if it's anyhow possible to store the colors in sphinx and perform the querying using the sphinx search engine?

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done search for colors with sphinx. It's there http://code.google.com/p/hppg/. How it works?
Very simple, for each color I store it's dominant colors in database. Database table, witch is used for sphinx indexing, has column named "colors", it's content is filled in the following way:

```
/**
     * This part was changed based on formula 
     * 
     * It fits here better than algorithm
     * 
     * http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tag_cloud
     * 15400 is number of maximum matches based on indexed thumbnail size 120x130 px.
     * */

   $max = 15400;
   $min = 25;
   $rmax = 50;
   $rmin = 1;

   $colorIndex = array();
   foreach ($colorsMaximumImage as $color)
   {
       $colorIndexString = trim(str_repeat(' pld'.$color['pallete_id'],round((($rmin*($color['count']-25))/($max-$min))*100)));
       if ($colorIndexString != '')
       $colorIndex[] = $colorIndexString;
   }
```

I used tagging formula here, to avoid very big index. Count is the number of times custom pallete item was matched. It works just fine, some examples of live sites can be found at project home page. Such way we can search by color and keyword at the same time :). Currently I'm still experimenting to get best result of it...

Comment: my approach is to generate a histogram with imagemagick and extract 10 most frequent and 10 most dominant colors and store these in mysql. so i have to index 10 rows for each photo in sphinx -- the index get's quite huge with this approach. you can see it for example here http://photo.clipdealer.com/media/499332 by clicking on one of the "color-gauges" in the info-box. thanks for your answer anyway, i give it a 'yes' because it's very helpful for me. thanks very much!

Comment: One more thing. Sphinx since 0.9.9 support select like filtering. So it would perfectly suit for your needs.

Comment: I'm working on a solution to a similar problem right now. While both approaches are helpful, I'd like to know if anyone has come up with a way to store all the color info on each record (as Remdex is doing) WITHOUT having to use a predefined color palette. Am I correct in thinking that Remdex's solution only allows searching by exact match?

Comment: About first I think you can use pdl_<red>_<green>_<blue> and repeat it by it's density. Of course that way text index can grow significantly, just need to experiment to get good results. In my approach searching does not have to be exact match. I' just implemented in gallery code it that way using sphinx extended search.